# What does "by as by" mean as method input description?

Tags: selenium

I have downloaded the latest seleniumbasic for vba and when trying to compile, the below code throws the error "Type Mismatch".

```
driver.isElementPresent("id=MerchantLogin")
```

When I look the details of the new version of the method it wants:

```
By As By, [timeout as Long]
```

I have searched far and wide and cannot find anything describing what "By As By" means.

https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/commit/9a706dfe41b5b74f25faa5812a4f352fc088a123

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the phrase "By As By", read it like this:

1. The first "By" can be replaced with "the first argument", and
2. "As" can be replace with "must be an instance of"
3. The second "By" can be replaced with "class selenium.webdriver.common.by.By"

To wit:

> The first argument must be an instance of class selenium.webdriver.common.by.By"

Comment: How likely is this to be the case for Selenium
Basic? (When I asked the question it would not let me tag it by SeleniumBasic.)

Comment: @flee: I don't understand your comment. If whatever version of selenium is telling you it must be of type `By`, then it must be of type `By`. You might have to refer to the actual `By` class differently, but the point is, the documentation is telling you the first argument needs to be a `By` object.

Comment: Fair enough. While I believe you are correct, I guess I don't know how to do that. I am reasonably certain this was the same in the previous version and this code worked there.